Why does the featured tab say that there is one bounty question even though there are none?
Title says it all. Here is a screenshot:


Hmm, curious - looks like the bounty wasn't awarded until 10:13GMT on 13 October, yet you saw this around 18:23 on 12 October (although the site's still posting that as "Yesterday":

One for the SE team really - although possibly a bit too localised (in that the featured tab is no longer appearing as there are no active bounties any more).

Seems like grace period questions count toward the number, but don't actually show up in the list. I'm not sure if this is by design or a bug.
